# in r, lognormal, glm, transformations, what should I do?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

(Updated)

I have biomass (grams) as my response variable, and weather data (wind, air temperature, relative humidity, precipitation) as well as vegetation measurements (basal area, canopy closure, stem counts) as explanatory variables.  I have some zeros in the data, like no wind speed (it just wasn't windy) or there was no precipitation for that day so it's 0.

I've also got different survey locations that I surveyed at different times.

I want to see what factors influence my response variable.  Hypothetically, there should be a model with something like this:

```
biomass~wind+airtemp+rH+precip+ba+closure+stems+(1|location)
```

I looked at the biomass data to see if they fit normal distributions:

```
library(car)
library(MASS)
qqp(biomass,"norm")
```

doesn't fit as well as `qqp(biomass,"lnorm")` so I think that a lognormal distribution fits it better right?

Also, following advice given in answers and comments (below) I graphed the residuals and I get a cone-shaped residuals vs fitted graph (= non constant variance) and a curved normal q-q plot.

Should my biomass should be logged? :

```
log(biomass)~wind+airtemp+rH+precip...
```

Or else should I transform my biomass data before adding them to the model?  (Although shouldn't `log(variable)` be the same as using a previously logged variable?

From previous answers and comments (see below), my equation has evolved into something like this:

```
library(lme4)

fit3=lmer(log(biomass)~wind+temp...+(1|location),data=mydata)
```

Plus, my adviser asked me to add treatment type (categorical variable) to the equation, so it really looks like this:

```
fit4=lmer(log(biomass)~treatmenttype+wind+temp....+(1|location),data=mydata)
```

When I try that though, I get some warning and error messages:

```
The variance-covariance matrix is not symmetric, returning NA matrix
There's an error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function
```

The R comments look like this:

```
Warning message:
In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
Computed variance-covariance matrix problem: matrix is not symmetric [1,2];
  returning NA matrix
Error in diag(vcov(object, use.hessian = use.hessian)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'diag': Error          in rr@factors$correlation <- if (!is.na(sigm)) as(rr, "corMatrix") else rr : 
  trying to get slot "factors" from an object of a basic class ("matrix") with no    slots
```

I'm not sure what this means.  Is this an error on my part in the regression or something I have wrong in the R code?

Comment: Why are you checking whether your explanatory variables are normal? Why are you checking the unconditional distribution of your response?

Comment: Glen_b - aren't you supposed to know if you need to transform your x-variables?

Comment: Why would you care what the distribution is at all? (I could maybe understand worrying about the distribution of the random effect or the error term but you don't seem to be looking at those.)

Comment: So you are saying it doesn't matter if the explanatory variables are logged?  Even when I try the function without logging the explanatory variables, it doesn't work...  I get the same error.  So what should I try?

Comment: It matters very much. I cannot tell from your information whether your variables should be on the log scale, the original scale or some other scale. You're *looking at the distribution of the variables* to decide what transformation to apply. It seems to suggest that you think they should have some particular distribution. Why are you doing that? Can you explain the reasoning?

Comment: I think because in regression you're supposed to know if your variables need to be transformed?  So you're supposed to do a qqp plot to see which distribution they fit?  If they're not normal then you're supposed to transform them?  Is that incorrect?  If that's not correct, can you suggest something that I should do instead?

Comment: Are you saying you think there's an assumption that the variables have some particular distribution in regression?

Comment: I'd consider transformation of predictor variables in glm or regression if I thought it would linearize the relationship on the scale of the linear predictor. The marginal distributions of the variables isn't really relevant.

Comment: So what should I do with my model?  I edited my original question to show a glm model that went through, but it's still giving me errors on some things.

Comment: Note that logging wind and precip would create problems with your zero values quite apart from @Glen_b's excellent advice.

Comment: Generalized linear models with logarithmic link do not require that all the data values be positive. The essential is only that conditional **means** be positive. So, the horrible fudge of log(response + constant) can and should be avoided. However, by asking specific questions about `lmer()` you run the risk of making this off-topic and/or removing from your readership those who are not fluent in R syntax.

Comment: Off-topic too, but log(something + constant) can hardly be difficult in R! More seriously, curvature on normal quantile plots need not mean nonlinearity; it could mean just that your distribution is not normal.

Comment: @ Nick Cox: I tried to just log the biomass but the function doesn't work.  I don't know if "Why is this happening?" is an lmer() question or a statistical question about logging y-values in  regression.  What should I do as far as my regression equation goes, if log(something+constant) should be avoided?

Comment: "doesn't work" is unfortunately uninformative; you have to say exactly what happened and why it puzzles or disappoints. GLMs with log link (should) automatically indulge zeros in the response. Sorry, but I can't advise on `lmer()` which I have never used, as I am only a very occasional R user. As I have no idea what it does, I can't advise on its statistical content either. There are many, many R users here who could be able to help, but once a subsidiary question is buried deep in comments, it's often overlooked. You could think about editing your question to flag what you need.

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of confusions here: most have probably been dealt with at one time or another on CrossValidated ...

- generally, the distributional assumptions of regression modeling (whether linear, generalized linear, or mixed) refer to the *conditional* distribution of the *response variable*: that is, the assumption is that $y \sim \textrm{Dist}(...)$, where the $...$ contains the information from the input variables (approximately the same as "predictor variables", "covariates", or "independent variables").
- sometimes people also transform the predictor variables, but this is to improve the linearity of the relationship between the input variables and the response.  There are very few cases where any important assumptions are made about the distribution of the input variables.
- if you have a continuous response variable, you can probably get away with a linear model (implemented via `lm()` in base R) or, if you want to include a random effect of site, `lmer()` from the `lme4` package (or `lme` from the `nlme` package).
- first you should plot your data. You should probably start by looking at univariate relationships (`plot(biomass~wind,data=mydata)`), even though they can miss a lot of higher-order structure.

I would probably try

```
  fit1 <- lm(biomass~.-location,data=mydata) 
  ## dot in the formula stands for "everything but the response"; 
  ##    -location takes out the location
  plot(fit1)   ## diagnostic plots
  ## maybe, if the Q-Q plot and scale-location plot look funny ...
  library("MASS")
  boxcox(fit1)
```

first, and then try the equivalent

```
library("lme4")
fit2 <- lmer(biomass~...,data=mydata)
## here you need to fill in the ... yourself since lme4 doesn't have the same
##  shortcuts
```

This is just scratching the surface, but might get you started.

Comment: Good advice. For a response variable like biomass log scale is often a better default. I suppose the Box-Cox is intended to show whether that is so. (I don't read R fluently.) Naturally, no one but the OP can see the dataset to give more detailed advice.

Answer (score -1):

As an initial approach, I'd try first to fit a logistic regression. I don't get why you are working with the log(variables). If poor performance is present then try to plot the error as a function of the size of the data to check if the poor performance is related to bias/variance issue. In case of high variance try more powerful models as Neural Networks etc...

Comment: The first suggestion is quite wrong on simple scientific grounds. The response is biomass measured in grams and not a binary variable at all. Whether other approaches might work better is always an open question, but the OP has to get GLMs working first before it can be seen how well they work.